# Passing C++ function arguments comprised of arrays of "new" objects

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am trying define a list of custom `IntervalDataState` objects that I can use to track statistics of some DAQ-measured values. In the below example, I want to keep track of the average, minimum, and maximum of temperature and humidity.  I would like to create a library from my code code, and use the same technique for different projects and be able to extend the library to other data types like bitmaps, integer values, etc., and to add different statistics I can choose from. Ideally, I would like the `IntervalDataState` list definitions to be encapsulated well so that I can easily share them on the client and server side.
This following seems to work, but seems ugly, especially the final definition of `IntervalDataState* ids_list[]`.
Is there a better way to do this?

(I am just providing the signatures of the classes below to keep this post a little shorter, but can add the class definitions if they are important.)

```
// base class signature for data state
class IntervalDataState {
    private:
    string name_;
    string units_;
    public:
    IntervalDataState(const string&, const string&);
    string& getName();
    string& getUnits();        
};

// Temperature in degC
class IDSTempDegC : public IntervalDataState {
    private:
    float min;
    float max;
    AccumFloat* accumList[];        // list of interval accumulators to use on this data signal
    public:
    IDSTempDegC(const string&, const string&, AccumFloat* accumList[], float min, float max);
};

// Percent (0-100)
class IDSPercent : public IntervalDataState {
    private:
    float min;
    float max;
    AccumFloat* accumList[];        // list of interval accumulators to use on this data signal
    public:
    IDSPercent(const string&, const string&, AccumFloat* accumList[]);
};
```

```
// base class signature for statistics
class AccumFloat {
    public:
        AccumFloat(){};                      // constructor
        virtual void reset(void) = 0;       // reset accumulator
        virtual void accum(float) = 0;      // accumulate new value
        virtual float val(void) = 0;        // calculate value of accumulator
        int getN(void);                     // get the number of points accumulated
    protected:
        int n = 0;                          // number of data points accumulated
};
        
class AccumFloatAvg : public AccumFloat {
    private:
        float cum;
    public:
        AccumFloatAvg();                         // constructor
        void reset(void);
        void accum(float);
        float val(void);
};

class AccumFloatMin : public AccumFloat {
    private:
        float min;
    public:
        AccumFloatMin();                         // constructor
        void reset(void);
        void accum(float);
        float val(void);
};
class AccumFloatMax : public AccumFloat {
    private:
        float max;
    public:
        AccumFloatMax();                         // constructor
        void reset(void);
        void accum(float);
        float val(void);
};
```

```
// testing it's use
int test() {
    AccumFloat* a1[] = {new AccumFloatAvg, new AccumFloatMin, new AccumFloatMax};
    AccumFloat* a2[] = {new AccumFloatAvg, new AccumFloatMin, new AccumFloatMax};
    IntervalDataState* ids_list[] = {
        new IDSTempDegC("temperature", "degC", a1, -100.0, 200.0),
        new IDSPercent("humidity", "%", a2)};
}
```

Also, I can't seem to put it all on one line.  I have tried other ways, but all generate compiler errors. For example, `error: no matching function for call to ‘ddnet::IDSTempDegC::IDSTempDegC(...` in this case...

```
IntervalDataState* ids_list[] = {
    new IDSTempDegC("temperature", "degC", {new AccumFloatAvg, new AccumFloatMin, new AccumFloatMax}, -100.0, 200.0),
    new IDSPercent("humidity", "%", {new AccumFloatAvg, new AccumFloatMin, new AccumFloatMax})};
```

"too many initializers..." on this one...

````
IntervalDataState* ids_list[] = {
    new IDSTempDegC("temperature", "degC", (AccumFloat **) {new AccumFloatAvg, new AccumFloatMin, new AccumFloatMax}, -100.0, 200.0),
    new IDSPercent("humidity", "%", (AccumFloat **) {new AccumFloatAvg, new AccumFloatMin, new AccumFloatMax})};```
````

Comment: C-style arrays are special, in that they can be initialized using a special syntax, like `type a[] = {any number of initializers};`. However, this is the *only* place this syntax can be used, arrays cannot be assigned or passed to functions using the `{ values }` format. It just doesn't work. Also, the `type a[]` without a size inside the `[]` can again *only* be used when directly initializing the array, it cannot be used for class members.

Comment: You seem to be coming to C++ from a language where `new` has a bit different meaning than in `C++`. In C++, there's no such a thing as "new" object. In C++ `operator new` returns a **pointer** to an object, which is typically allocated on the heap. 

The next point are arrays. C++ has inherited "plain old arrays" from the C language, but after many years of development, now their usage is discouraged. They are usually replaced by `std::array` or, more often, by `std::vector`. I could help you if you tell me if you really insist on these pointers and plain arrays.

Comment: Thanks guys.  Based on your comments, I did a bit more reading and I think I have a decent understanding now and have taken a slightly different approach.  I switched to `std::vector` as suggested, and that enables me to get the whole initializer on one line, although that's not really critical anymore because of some other changes.